# Is there anything significantly different about compiling a kernel module for WindRiver Linux vs a standard desktop build?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am attempting to compile a kernel module (pmem.ko from http://www.rekall-forensic.com/, not that it should matter). In the past, compiling this module has been a matter of using the following lines in the Makefile:

```
pmem: pmem.c
    $(MAKE) -C $(KHEADER) O=$(KOUTPUT) M=$(PWD) modules
```

KHEADER is set to the location of the kernel headers. If the kernel was origionally built with the O= flag, KOUTPUT is set to match. Otherwise, it matches KHEADER.

Now I get error messages such as the following:

```
make: Entering directory `<KHEADER>'
  CC [M]  <pwd>/module.o
In file included from <KHEADER>/include/linux/module.h:10,
             from <PWD>/module.c:4:
<KHEADER>/include/linux/sched.h:4:36: error: asm/param.h: No such file or directory
```

Note: I have replaced actual paths with the contents of the variables.

There are is one notable difference that I can see between this attempt and the others. In previous working builds, all output products seemed to be in the same output (including the .config file). In this example, the .config file is with the kernel source, not the output directory. I fixed the errors that caused by copying the .config file to what appears to me to be the OUTPUT directory.

I guess what I'm asking is whether the standard method of building a linux kernel module is expected to work with the WindRiver variant, or whether adjustments need to be made for a different build process.

Comment: shouldn't -C be followed by the build directory?

Comment: In past (working) experience, KHEADER can either be the full source tree, or just the headers. But yes, it is a build directory that has a Makefile and a suitable .config file. Alternatively, if the KOUTPUT directory is specified, the .config file should be there.

Comment: ok, I was asking because this looked like the kind of errors you get when using a non configured kernel tree. Did you try WindRiver support site?

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to copy the .config.

In fact you should rebuilt the kernel or use the sources path for the KHEADER.

You built the kernel without the O= flag